# An exercise in Elementary Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove (logically) that:
If ($x\ge a \implies x\ge b$) then $a\ge b$.

($x$ positive and unknown and $a,b\in\mathbb N^+$).

Comment: I think it is the other way round. Consider $x = 4$, then we have $x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3 \Rightarrow 2 > 3$? The implication is not dependent on the inequality $a \geqslant b$, but rather the value of $x$. Therefore, the implication is only dependent on $a \geqslant b$ if and only if $x = a$. Perhaps you mean that if $x \geqslant a \Rightarrow x \geqslant b$ then $\diamond \ a \geqslant b$

Comment: Your question is confusing, and one reason is that you use two different ways to show implication, and another reason is that you have no parentheses so the grouping is not clear, and yet another is that you have no quantifiers. Do you mean that you want a proof of the statement $[(\forall x)(x\ge a \implies x\ge b)]\implies a\ge b$?

Comment: yes i mean exactly this

Comment: If my final edited comment is what you mean, then the answer by blueplusgreen is correct.

Comment: but is that a "proof" for all unkown x?

Comment: The quantifier over $x$ is inside the "if" part of the overall implication. So that quantified statement is not necessarily true for the overall implication to be true. Thus no proof for all unknown $x$ is needed. If that inner statement is true, namely for all $x$, then that "then" part of the overall implication is true. That means the overall implication is true. This is somewhat confusing, but that is true of much quantified logic.

Comment: i confess that this is easy but confusing : what if the quantifier is outside ?...like a theorem to be proved for all x.

Answer (score 2):

If the implication is true for every $x$, it's particularity true for $x=a$.

Apply it to the logical sentence and get the desired result.

Comment: we dont "know" that its true for all x , we want the exact proof that its true

Comment: Then please edit/ rewrite your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

$X >= B$ if and only if $X >= A$.  This means that if $X >= A$ would mean $X >=B$.  So it definitely holds true that $A >= B$.